# Filter records using multiple groupings and preserve columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below table data

[image]

As you can see for a given student there are multiple records in one year and multiple schools. the result I need to take is filter student according to below criteria

- if the Student has multiple schools in a same year take the records which has latest enrollment date
- If the Student has only one record for a year , take the latest enrolment record

Finally I would only have one record per student.
So after that i should only have data like highlighted below,

[image]

I have tried many groupings to get this and the problem is, it will omit some columns. But i need to take all the columns listed here.

```
select max(val.sc_year) as lyear, max(val.enroll_date) as ldate,val.stident_id,val.student_name,val.school
from table val group by val.stident_id,val.student_name,val.school
```

Comment: Does the query giving some error?

Comment: You need to make up your mind. In words you say you want to get the most recent row for every student **and year**, but later (and in the example) you select only one row per student. You don't seem to care about year at all. So which is it?

Comment: distinct students should take based on the latest enrolment date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get the most recent row for every student and year.
below query will help you.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT StusdentId, EnrolmentDate, Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY StusdentId ORDER By EnrolmentDate desc)
        AS SRNo 
        FROM [StudentTable]  
) AS B WHERE SRNo=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below should work, at least it will return the yellow rows, so only one record per student independent on how many years he studied:

```
select val.sc_year as lyear, val.enroll_date as ldate,val.stident_id,val.student_name,val.school 
from table val 
where 
  concat(val.enroll_date, val.student_id) in 
     (select concat(max(val.enroll_date), val.student_id) from val 
      group by val.student_id)
```